# Android Redirect to URL (ADFS) issue

Tags: community, salesforce1-app, sfdcmobilesdk-android, mobilepush-android, salesforce-sdk-android

I am facing an issue while login with ADFS.Showing Blank Page in Android.

Steps: Change Server -> Add Connection -> Added my custom salesforce server. then i can able to view the Login Page. In login page i have additional option like (or Login) Using(Your ADFS Id).If i tap on that option it was showing blank page.I don't have any problem with IOS . But it was happen only in android. Will you please help to fix this issue.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 WebView change height android:layout_height="match_parent" Fixed my issue
```